# Is "backporting" Python 3's `range` to Python 2 a bad idea?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

One of my classes requires assignments to be completed in Python, and as an exercise, I've been making sure my programs work in both Python 2 and Python 3, using a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Run some PyUnit tests
python2 test.py
python3 test.py
```

One thing I've been doing is making `range` work the same in both versions with this piece of code:

```
import sys

# Backport Python 3's range to Python 2 so that this program will run
# identically in both versions.
if sys.version_info < (3, 0):
    range = xrange
```

Is this a bad idea?

EDIT:

The reason for this is that `xrange` and `range` work differently in Python 2 and Python 3, and I want my code to do the same thing in both. I could do it the other way around, but making Python 3 work like Python 2 seems stupid, since Python 3 is "the future".

Here's an example of why just using `range` isn't good enough:

```
for i in range(1000000000):
    do_something_with(i)
```

I'm obviously not using the list, but in Python 2, this will use an insane amount of memory.

Comment: It really doesn’t work with Python 2’s range?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a bad idea, but it would be a bad to reuse the name `range`.  If I see `range` in Python 2.x code, I would expect it to return a list and not an iterator and not have to search through the code to see if the name has been reassigned.  It probably would be easier to use a different name all together or even reuse `xrange` instead as it's not defined in Python 3.x.

Comment: What are you doing that works with `xrange` but not Python 2.x's `range`?

Comment: @JeffMercado Post answers as answers.  Why make this a comment?

Comment: @dkamins: I generally leave my opinions as comments and statements that I can back up, I would consider making an answer.  I was considering posting that as an answer (still have my answer drafted) but it turned to be mostly opinion AFAIK as I don't really know what the best thing to do here is with regards to python's expected coding standards.

Comment: @Jeff Mercado - The idea of redefining `xrange` in Python 3 is interesting. My goal was more to write the code "as Python 3" and then use a couple hacks to make it work in an older interpreter (so I can write it how I want, but it will run anywhere).

Comment: It's not a bad idea, although for complex projects I would use 2to3 instead of making it run under both Python 2 and Python 3. But for smaller projects supporting both versions is a good idea, made simpler by `six`. See also http://python3porting.com/noconv.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [six](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/six/) package which provides a Python 2 and 3 compatibility library and written by one of the Python core developers.  Among its features is a set of standard definitions for renamed modules and functions, including `xrange` -> `range`.  The use of `six` is one of many recommendations in the official [Porting Python 2 Code to Python 3 HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/py3k/howto/pyporting.html) included in the Python Documentation set.

Answer (score 6):

What you probably *should* be doing is making sure it works cleanly under 2.x, and then passing it through [`2to3`](http://docs.python.org/library/2to3.html) and verifying that the result works cleanly in 3.x. That way you won't have to go through hoops such as redefining `range` as you have already done.

Comment: there's also the [3to2](https://bitbucket.org/amentajo/lib3to2/overview) project, which builds on the lib2to3 framework to provide fixers and a script for doing the reverse, it may be more useful in this case.

Comment: How is 2 lines of code "jumping through hoops", but passing it through `2to3` constantly isn't?

Comment: It's two lines of code *now*. Who knows how many changes will be required once done.

Comment: Well, one thing you can do is to run the code through 2to3 to see how many changes are done. And if you develop in parallell for 2 and 3, the differences needed are usually small, especially if you use `six`.