# Does range involve eager or lazy evaluation, in 2.x and 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, range, lazy-evaluation, python-2.x

I was looking at the `range` function and an online search shows that (EDIT: in 2.x) it's [eagerly evaluated](https://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/range.html)

```
>>> range(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

However when I try the code below in my local Python3.3 interpreter

```
a = range(10)
print(a)
```

I get an output

```
range(0, 10)
```

**That's something I'd expect from a lazy evaluated function, what's the case ?**

Note : In Python2.7 it always behaves as eagerly evaluated.

Comment: @roippi Is it though ? How you'd expect someone who's primary language isn't Python to reach that other post ? I'm asking on terms ubiquitous across programming languages *eager* vs *lazy* **after** my Google search gave me just confusion on the topic

Comment: Tagged [tag:python-2.x],[tag:python-3.x],[tag:range],[tag:lazy-evaluation]. Be aware that there may be version differences, so redo the keyword search with '2.x'/2.7/2.6 and '3.x' and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou: you're right, but hang on. Closing-as-duplicate is not about chastizing the asker for (re-)asking what might be a perfectly relevant and important question (as in this case) but under a different set of terms/keywords/tags. Closing-as-duplicate is purely about keeping ***all equivalent questions on a single topic pointing to a single SO resource***. (See Meta.SO/.SE for endless debate...)

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou That's the whole point; the whole reason your google search didn't work for you is that there aren't enough signposts linking (the terminology you searched for) with (the answer you were seeking).  Duplicates serve as signposts connecting posts with their correct canonical answer.

Comment: See also [Is “backporting” Python 3's `range` to Python 2 a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507492/is-backporting-python-3s-range-to-python-2-a-bad-idea)

Comment: A search on [lazy evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation#Simulating_laziness_in_eager_languages) would also give you the answer.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535342/lazy-evaluation-python

Answer (score 11):

The behavior was changed between Python 2 and 3.  In Python 2, it creates a list, so it is effectively eagerly evaluated.  In Python 3, it creates a range object, whose individual values are lazily evaluated.

In Python 2, `xrange` provides a lazy version of `range`.  In Python 3, if you want to force the whole lazy object to be evaluated into a real list, you can do `list(range(10))`.

Answer (score 2):

As with all things, the situation in PyPy is weirder.  In short, [it's *both*.](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/3777204fff8ea4ee1d2748bd3d7f485af2c040c6/pypy/objspace/std/listobject.py?at=default#cl-1100)

Specifically, when a python2 program calls `range()`, the return value has type `list`, but its *implementation* is actually more like `types.XRangeType`; until you try to modify it, at which point it creates a "real" list.